# impossible to prove something

Tags: logic

(Edited by comments)

Let sentence P and Q are under this situation:

, in logic of ZFC theory

> Pvbl( P(X) ) → { if  Pvbl(Q)  then  X(X) }
>
> Q≡ ¬pvlb( P(P) )

using fixed point theorem, let's make it more clearly.

> Pvbl( P ) → { if  Pvbl(Q)  then  P }
>
> Q≡ ¬pvlb( P )

claim: under the assumption of consistency of ZFC, Q is not provable

proof of claim:

Assume Pvbl(Q), Then, ZFC proves "Prv(Q)".

so ZFC proves " Prv(P) → P  " by modus ponons

by Lob theorem, P is provable.

But Q implies ¬(Pvbl(P), so P is disprovable.

P is provable and disprovable. It means ZFC is inconsistent.

But we assumed that ZFC is consistent.

Therefore, Q is not provable.

Q.E.D.

Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: Your definition of $P$ is circular, i.e. it refers to itself in the definition.

Comment: @xyzzyz diagonalization method can be used here. For example, P(X)≡if ( ZFC  ⊢ Q ) then ( ZFC ⊢ X(X) ) and Q≡P(P) is not provable.  Fixed point theorem also can be used here. such P exist...

Comment: I edited it by your comment.

Comment: The question seems to indicate that you have not yet completely understood the difference between saying "ZFC proves Z" and "ZFC proves Pvbl(Z)". In particular, both of the $\vdash$ near the top of the question should be Pvbl.  ZFC cannot refer to the actual $\vdash$ relation.

Comment: @CarlMummert I edited. Now is correct?

Comment: are you saying "P(P) implies automatically ( Pvbl(P(P)) )" inside ZFC?    It's very unclear when you are switching between the object and the meta language.

Comment: I think you are using Löb's theorem in the wrong direction.

Comment: Sorry. I just thought that { ( A ≡ if B then C ) and (B is provable)  }results (A implies C).  Maybe error reasoning.

Comment: Yes, that is not correct reasoning. For example, ZFC proves the statement A = "$0 = 1 \to 1 = 2$", but "Pvbl(0=1)" does not imply $A \to 1 = 2$. You are mixing real provability with formalized provability. It is true that if $ZFC \vdash B \to C$ and $ZFC \vdash B$ then $ZFC \vdash C$.

Comment: ok, actually you are right about that part, but the way you phrased it very confusing..  what you have is this:

assume ZFC proves "Q".
then   ZFC proves "Prv(Q)".
so     ZFC proves "P(P) -> Prv(P(P))" by modus ponons

but then when you go to use Lob, you're using it backwards.

Comment: i dunno, lets try

Comment: @LarryD'Anna I did edit from your comments.

Comment: @HoCheolSHIN  what did you do to the definiton of P?    I think it was a lot more clear what you meant before.

Comment: I actually think your original impredicative definitions of P and Q were clearest, and justified by the usual fixed point shenanigans.

Comment: @LarryD'Anna it was just P instead of P(P). Pvbl( P ) → { if Pvbl(Q) then P }.

Comment: @LarryD'Anna I changed the direction also. Original was P≡{ if Pvbl(Q) then pvbl(P) }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8437/discussion-between-hocheol-shin-and-larry-danna)

Comment: OK, but now how do you justify that ZFC proves "Prv(P(P)) -> P(P)" in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conclusion is correct, but the argument is not.   ZFC will not prove Q because Q implies Con(ZFC), which we can't have by Gödel. however you are using Lob's Thorem backwards.     Lob says if you can prove "Prbl(X) -> X" then you can prove "X", not the other way around.

(edit):   I think we've resolved the confusion.   The argument is this:  Let P and Q be sentences such that ZFC proves "Prv(P) -> Prv(Q) -> P" and "Q <-> ~Prv(P)"  then (assuming it's consistent) ZFC doesn't prove Q.

proof:  if it does, then it proves "Prv(Q)", so it proves "Prv(P) -> P", so it proves P by Lob, so it proves "Prv(P)", so it proves "~Q"

Comment: in the beginning, I said "under the assumption of consistency of ZFC"......

Comment: how does consistency of ZFC give you ZFC proving P(P)?

Comment: By definition of P(P) ≡ if ( ZFC ⊢ Q ) then ( ZFC ⊢ P(P) )

Comment: @HoCheol SHIN: even if we assume ZFC is consistent, ZFC does not prove Con(ZFC). In fact, when we assume ZFC is consistent, the incompleteness theorem tells us that one thing ZFC will not prove is Con(ZFC). But then ZFC cannot prove Q either, as Larry D'Anna has explained.

Comment: HoCheol, perhaps you could spell out as precisely as you can why you think that it ZFC will prove P(P).

Comment: I edited question by comments from @CarlMummert...